# NetLogo - how to sort patches top-bottom only

Tags: patch, netlogo

I have a field of patches specified as "water"(all patches, which are below 0 point in the y axis, except the last "bottom" one). Above water is air:

```
set water-top 0
set water patches with [ pycor < 0 and pycor > min-pycor ]
set air patches with [ pycor > water-top ]
```

They have an attribute to them:

```
patches-own [ heat ]
```

I want "water" to be sorted top to bottom only.
The model should take some "heat" from the "air" and distribute it through the "water' top-down, meaning that the top layers get more heat and bottom ones - less.

```
  ask air [ set heat 1 ]
  ask water [ set heat 0 ]
  foreach sort water [  ;; *Sort top-to-bottom needed here*
    ask ? [
      *some heat distributing code*
    ]
  ]
```

Thanks for your help. I couldn't find anything in the manual, only that a sort-by needs to be used.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It looks correct to me. `sort` does sort top-to-bottom.

Comment: An alternative approach might be to do your computations using `pycor`, or loop a row at a time using `pycor`. Whether this would be appropriate in your case, I can't say, since you haven't told us enough about what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using pycor as an altitude proxy and you want the heat to move downwards? Patches are fixed pieces of the world - they can't be moved. So for your purposes they are already in the correct sort order. What you really want is something like (not also minor changes I made to your code so that water-top had an effect and that water existed down to the bottom and up to the air, and added colour so you could see the purpose of changing the < to <= etc)

```
set water-top 0
set water patches with [ pycor <= water-top and pycor >= min-pycor ]
set air patches with [ pycor > water-top ]

ask air
[ set color white
  set heat 1
]

ask water
[ set color blue
  set heat calculate-heat (water-top - pycor)
]

to calculate-heat depth
  ; code that converts depth into heat
end
```

The above code will do the heat allocation in a single tick. If you want the heat to actually move downward through time, then you will need to have time put into your model and the code you need to ask the patches to do something in the appropriate order is:

```
foreach sort-on [- pycor] water
  [ ask ? [ do-something that looks at heat of above patch] ]
```

so that the highest pycor patches are done first

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. I'll try it out. In case of success I'll mark as answered.